# XCode 4: adding parsekit library to project

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, parsekit

I'm using XCode 4.2 and I'm trying to add the parsekit library to my project, this is what I did:

1. Drag the ParseKit.xcodeproj to my project in XCode as a Sub Project.
2. Adding the libparsekit.a to the link binary with libraries list
3. Trying to compile, everything still works.

Adding this to my code:

```
#import <ParseKit/ParseKit.h>
```

Then I've tried typing some code, and autocomplete works, so it must have found the library... But when I compile, I get this error:

```
'ParseKit/ParseKit.h' file not found
```

I also tried to replace the import with the following lines of code, but nothing worked, they all gave the same error...

```
#import "ParseKit/ParseKit.h"
#import "ParseKit.h"
#import <ParseKit.h>
```

Anyone got an idea on how to resolve this problem?

Here's a video on how I imported ParseKit into my project:
http://youtu.be/xjF8c2vo9vA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer of ParseKit here. Please checkout the instructions for ParseKit on iOS here:

http://parsekit.com/iphone.html

Although the instructions are from Xcode 3, I think you are missing steps 7 & 8.

Comment: Just did that, however, I'm still getting the same error. Also, the libparsekit.a is displayed in a red color in the link binary with libraries list.

Comment: I just tried it again, I've made a new project, and I did the XCode 4.2 equivalent to every step in the instructions, but still, I'm getting the same error: "file not found". I'm getting really desperate about this...

Comment: I've editted my question and included a video in it that shows how I added the project, and which error I'm getting...

Comment: Thanks for the video. That helps a ton. The header search path you are using has a possible issue. There's whitespace in the path (`Xcode projects`). That might be breaking the search path. So try adding quotes around the entire path.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot! I will reward the bounty to you (tomorrow or so, I can only reward it in 20 hours) ;-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the whitespace in your search path is the issue. I just followed all of your steps in the video myself (Ccode 4.2, Lion 10.7.2), and was able to build.